# Tabris Button Height

Tags: button, multiline, tabris

I'm trying to make a multiline button, but the text gets cut off.

```
Button button = new Button( containerButton, SWT.PUSH );
button.setText( "Hello\nWorld" );
```

Is it possible to adjust the height of a button?
The only thing I found was setSize( width, height ) but that's not working.

Thanks! 
Toby

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the button a layout data e.g. a GridData. Here you can set e.g. the heightHint. This should work.

Maybe a good article to read would be:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html